# Need to add another entry (--Select--) dynamically to DropDownList in my views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm assigning values to my **dropdownlist** in my views as shown below.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Sites", new SelectList(Model.SiteList.Select(x => new { Value = x.SiteId, Text = x.SiteName }), "Value", "Text"))
```

How can I add another list item called as `'--Select--'`

Comment: You mean `optionLabel`? You can pass option label string as a third parameter.

Comment: You can simplify you code to `new SelectList(Model.SiteList, "SiteId", "SiteName ")` - creating an anonymous first is a bit pointless

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike and Stephen. I got the solution. I'm using the below code and its working fine. @Html.DropDownList("Sites", new SelectList(Model.SiteList, "SiteId", "SiteName"),"--Select--")

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add it as the last parameter:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Sites", 
        new SelectList(Model.SiteList.Select(x => 
             new { Value = x.SiteId, Text = x.SiteName }), "Value", "Text"), "--Select--");
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8h9nML)**

Comment: Thank you buddy. The below code seems quite easy. @Html.DropDownList("Sites", new SelectList(Model.SiteList, "SiteId", "SiteName"),"--Select--")

Answer (score 1):

```
@{
  var values = Model.SiteList.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.SiteId, Text = x.SiteName }).ToList();
  values.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "--Select--" });
}

@Html.DropDownList("Sites", new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text"))
```

Comment: Creating a 2nd identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one using `new SelectList()` is a bit pointless.